# when calling post method it enters the if statement when the password corresponds, but my res in the if statement is ignored, why?

Tags: node.js, authentication, post, postman

I am new to nodejs, and I'm trying to make a login system. This is my login Post:

[login post code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrlRw.png)

It enters in the if statement (which means the password corresponds) but my Res.status is ignored. I am using postman to see if it works, and it returns the other Res.status out of the if statement. The next image shows that:

[image: postman print]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you call `finally` which is called regardless of the success or error of the authentication. Try removing the call to `finally`.

Why was your 404 code invoked before the then/catch? Because it was not inside the finally callback but just invoked in the post handler.

If you would code this like:

```
finally( () => res.status(400).json({...}) )
```

It would be invoked after the then/catch. Your code made it happen before. It wad evaluated before the Promise was resolved or rejected.

Look at the following example

```
function sendError() {
   ...
}

getUser()
   .then(response => ...)
   .catch(err => ... )
   .finally( sendError() );
```

In my example, `sendError` is always called before getUser(). It's the same in your code.

Nevertheless, if you do it properly inside the callback for `finally`, it would throw an error because the response was already sent.

Hopes that makes it clear

Comment: router.post('/login', async (req, res) =>{
   
    User.find({ username: req.body.username}).exec()
    .then( utilizador=>{
        utilizador.forEach(element => { 
           if(passwordHash.verify(req.body.password, element.password)){
                console.log('utilizador logado');
                res.status(200).json({ message: 'logado' });
                console.log('utilizador logado');
           }
        });
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.status(500).end();
    })
    
    res.status(404).json({ message: 'erro de autenticacao'});
   
})

Comment: like that ? still gives the same error, and thanks for the help

Comment: I meant remove the entire res.status(404).json({...})

Comment: so it works, but i am a litle confused, why was it running the last res ? i thought that when entering the if statement it would give the res (200) and leave, why does it go first on the last res and leave? its kinda confusing.
thanks for the help, really appreciated!!

Comment: Okay, I have read the code again and will explain. I'll edit the answer to add clarification

Comment: Yes, this was easier to understand! thanks for the help!